# NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented In Angular,Breeze,OData

Tags: angularjs, odata, breeze

I working with a sample which will display contents from OData using Angular and Breezejs

index.html

```
<!docttype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <script src="datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="LearnCtrl">
  <p ng-show="!results">Fetching...</p>
  <li ng-show="results" ng-repeat="result in results">
   <span>{{result.Login}}</span>
   <span>{{result.Email}}</span>
  </li>   
  </div> 

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://sampleservice.breezejs.com/scripts/q.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://sampleservice.breezejs.com/scripts/breeze.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
 app.controller("LearnCtrl", function($scope) {
  var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost:8083/WordPress2.svc');

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from("User");

manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
   $scope.results = data.results;
   $scope.$apply();
}).fail(function(e) {
    alert(e);  
});
});
```

i am executing the code using ISS7 server...
when i say localhost:8082...in console.log it saying

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8083/WordPress2.svc/$metadata 501 (Not Implemented) datajs-1.0.3.js:1074
OPTIONS http://localhost:8083/WordPress2.svc/$metadata Origin http://localhost:8082 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. datajs-1.0.3.js:1074
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8083/WordPress2.svc/$metadata. Origin http://localhost:8082 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. localhost/:1
```

Should be empty: [] 
  why i am getting this error...
plz help me...this is my first app using these technologies...

Comment: You are making cross domain request as the port are different 8082 and 8083. Search how to setup cross domain request handling which requires server and client change, or better still use the same url + port combination.

Comment: @Chandermani:localhost:8083/WordPress2.svc is OdataPHPproducer sample code...localhost:8082 is my code...how can i combine these two..??

Comment: By combining i mean hosting then under one website, not on different ports.

Comment: @Chandermani:that is also not possible...

Comment: @Chandermani:how can i include these two files in ODataPhpProducer